# Need advice on a layout structure to use for dynamically created table of questions - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, dynamic, tablelayout

I need to design a layout for a table of questions for a survey. The number of questions is fixed, but the number of responses is not fixed.

See a drawing of the table structure I have in mind: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLGIG.jpg

The requirements I have are:

- The number of names in the top row can vary and if there are too many, the table should be able to scroll horizontally.
- The number of questions could be more than what is able to fit on the screen. The table should then be able to scroll vertically.
- Horizontal scrolling should start at column B, thus column A for the questions are fixed.
- Vertical scrolling should start at row 2, thus the first row is also fixed.
- The row heights should align. Specifically the questions text should align with the other cells in the row. The question text will for most cases be more than one row high.
- Columns of equal width would look the best.

The columns from B onwards will be added dynamically at run time, so I need some advice on what is the best layout structure to use to accomplish the end result in the most efficient (least time coding) way. Keep in mind that I will also have to populate the views with answers if an existing answer set needs to be edited.

At the moment I am looking at using a TableLayout, but it has its limitations.The other option is a custom layout to use as a list item in a listview.

Any thoughts or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest potentially a horizontal linear layout with 2 columns.  In each of the columns have a listview.  In the left-most one, your column A will go, and in the Right one you essentially do the same but each row will have multi-values.

from here, you could connect the two scroll actions, when the right one scrolls, you would have to manually scroll the left, and vice versa.

Here is also a great tutorial on listviews

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I ended up discarding the table idea and rather split the questions in horizontal sections.